# Matrix-field with a category-field to output category-title on single entry page

Tags: craft3, matrix, categories, field, category

Me and categories, always giving trouble :)

On blogs, we are using a matrix field and in one of the matrix-types, I have a category field.
This is to output the title of the category.

```
{% extends "matrix/default" %}
 {% block blockContent %}
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col flexcntr">
    {% set merk = block.merkNaam %}
    {{ merk.title }}
  </div>    
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

The outcome is empty ...

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, the problem is solved.

I just need to loop over the categories.

```
{% extends "matrix/default" %}
{% block blockContent %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col flexcntr">
        {% for merk in block.merkNaam %}
            {{ merk.title }}
        {% endfor %} #}
    </div>  
</div>
{% endblock %}
```